# How to hide contents from other authenticated users except it's owner?

Tags: permissions, plone

Plone 4.2

I create a folder and enable "Sharing"-"Can add" for Logged-in users to uploade files. Now I hope the files uploaded by authenticated user A is invisble to other authenticated users. Is this possible? If so, How?

Best Regards.

Hugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the intranet_workflow.

Then subtract the 'View'-permission of contributors via the permissions-tab of the private-state:

http://yourhost.org:8888/yourSiteId/portal_workflow/intranet_workflow/states/private/manage_properties

Update the security settings afterwards by hitting the button on the bottom of:

http://yourhost.org:8888/yourSiteId//portal_workflow/manage_selectWorkflows

This should actually be the default behaviour, IMHO. If you are motivated, you might bring this up as a proposal.

Comment: This works. But need to give contributor role to group authenticated users. Thanks.

Comment: Assigning the 'Add'-permission via the sharing-tab, as you wrote, grants the contributor-role, already. Anyway, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

By default Plone File contents are without workflow.

You must apply a workflow to them, the kind of workflow is not important, more important is that the initial state must be a "private" state, where no-one (apart Owner and Manager+ Site Administrator) behave the "View" permission.

Comment: I tested simple workflow, it does not work. But intranet_workflow works.  Thanks.